# Python3: Change one character of item in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I have a list like this:

```
['ID|number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2|number3|number4|-|name2|location2']
```

The list is generated from a dictionary, and contains the dictionary's keys. I
would like to change the first '|' into a '='.

I tried this:

```
keyList=[]
for item in finalDict.keys():
    keyList.append(item)

z=0
for item in keyList:
    for letter in item:
        if letter=='|':
            z+=1
            if z==1:
                letter.replace('|', '=')
```

But I did not get an error or my desired output

```
Actual output:
    ['ID|number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2|number3|number4|-|name2|location2']


Desired output:
    ['ID=number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2=number3|number4|-|name2|location2']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to change the first '|' into a '='

In simple way:

```
keyList = ['ID|number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2|number3|number4|-|name2|location2']
result = [k.replace('|', '=', 1) for k in keyList]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['ID=number1|number2|+|name|location', 'ID2=number3|number4|-|name2|location2']
```

---

- **`str.replace(old, new[, count])`** - if the optional argument `count` is
      given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Comment: Now, I even remember reading this. The docs for str.replace, but I simply skipped the count option. Thank you all for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

```
l=['ID|number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2|number3|number4|-|name2|location2']

j=[]
for i in l:
    i=i.replace("|","=",1)
    j.append(i)

print(j)
```

Output

```
['ID=number1|number2|+|name|location', 'ID2=number3|number4|-|name2|location2']
```

Comment: thank you, I missed, that I can specifiy the position, where to replace! This simplifies my program and reduces my loops :)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehesion  + regex

```
import re 
theList=['ID|number1|number2|+|name|location','ID2|number3|number4|-|name2|location2']

print [ re.sub(r'(ID.?)\|',r'\1=',item) for item in theList]
```